# Simple_html_dom.php Find fails when using 2 versions of file_get_contents

Tags: php

This code works on site a:

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.aaa.co.uk/Products/decking-screw-green');
echo $html;
foreach($html->find('div[id=produttabs]') as $xxx) {
echo $xxx;    
}
```

On another site I don't get anything returned so I found this code:

```
$opts = array('http'=>array('header' => "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n"));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html1 =file_get_contents('http://bbbb/0/p/FORSTCK126Z',false,$context);
echo $html1;
$ret = $html1->find('div[class=panel marBottom20]', 0);
echo 'ret ='.$ret;
```

Both echo's show the page returned but on the second code I get :

Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/xxx/public_html/xxx/techy/getimages.php on line 28.

The class 'panel marBottom20' exists in $html1 when I inspect the page.

What am I not understanding here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents returns a string so it has no method find. It is a method defined in 'simple_html_dom.php'

Comment: find is a function of 'simple_html_dom.php'

Answer (score 0):

My Bad.

I noticed my error through copying and pasting.
I was using file_get_contents in the second code instead of file_get_html.